# Неправильно обрабатывается кнопка

Tags: stm32

#### Описание

STM32F103C8Tx.
1 кнопка (4 ножки, не SMD), 1 7-сегментный дисплей.
Пытаюсь сделать 2 вывода - часы, секундомер (или любой другой раздел) (нажал на кнопку - показывает часы, нажал - секундомер)
Обработку кнопок делаю в таймере:

```
void TIM3_IRQHandler(void)
{
  HAL_TIM_IRQHandler(&htim3);

  if(HAL_GPIO_ReadPin(GPIOB, GPIO_PIN_1)) {
    if(mode == 0)
        mode = 1;
    else
        mode = 0;
  }
}
```

Кнопка объявлена так:

```
  GPIO_InitStruct.Pin = GPIO_PIN_1;
  GPIO_InitStruct.Mode = GPIO_MODE_INPUT;
  GPIO_InitStruct.Pull = GPIO_NOPULL;
  HAL_GPIO_Init(GPIOB, &GPIO_InitStruct);
```

Пытался сделать PULLUP и подключить к GND - не работала вообще. Сделал NOPULL и подключил к 3V3
На данный момент схема такая:[image: Схема]

Таймер запускаю так:

```
  HAL_TIM_Base_Start(&htim3);
  HAL_TIM_Base_Start_IT(&htim3);
```

И объявлен он так:

```
htim3.Instance = TIM3;
  htim3.Init.Prescaler = 35999;
  htim3.Init.CounterMode = TIM_COUNTERMODE_UP;
  htim3.Init.Period = 999;
  htim3.Init.ClockDivision = TIM_CLOCKDIVISION_DIV1;
  htim3.Init.AutoReloadPreload = TIM_AUTORELOAD_PRELOAD_DISABLE;
  if (HAL_TIM_Base_Init(&htim3) != HAL_OK)
  {
    Error_Handler();
  }
  sClockSourceConfig.ClockSource = TIM_CLOCKSOURCE_INTERNAL;
  if (HAL_TIM_ConfigClockSource(&htim3, &sClockSourceConfig) != HAL_OK)
  {
    Error_Handler();
  }
  sMasterConfig.MasterOutputTrigger = TIM_TRGO_RESET;
  sMasterConfig.MasterSlaveMode = TIM_MASTERSLAVEMODE_DISABLE;
  if (HAL_TIMEx_MasterConfigSynchronization(&htim3, &sMasterConfig) != HAL_OK)
  {
    Error_Handler();
  }
```

Вывод делаю в основном цикле (думаю, код показывать не стоит - просто проверка на переменную mode, если 0 - выводить часы, 1 - секундомер, или что-то ещё)

#### Проблема

При запуске - всё нормально. Нажимаю на кнопку переходит на другой режим, нажал - обратно на часы. Но через неск. секунд - начинает само переключать режимы, хотя я до кнопки вообще не дотрагивался. В чём может быть проблема?

Comment: Попробуйте выставить подтяжку к земле - `GPIO_PULLDOWN`

Comment: @MaximTimakov Спасибо! Пока что всё работает